# Combinatorics - 12 boxes, 3 persons, 4 each

Tags: combinatorics

Having some trouble understanding a question about combinatorics.
The problem:

You and your 2 friends have just bought 12 boxes. In how many ways can you carry them if each and one of you have to carry 4 each?

Can anyone help me understand it?

Comment: Are the boxes identical?

Answer (score 2):

You pick 4 packets in $\binom{12}{4}$ ways. Then the first friend chooses 4 from the remaining 8 in $\binom{8}{4}$ ways. The final set is fixed. So multiply. This is assuming the boxes are all different, of course.

This is also denoted $\binom{12}{4,4,4}$ as well, which by definition counts this number and has as its formula $\frac{12!}{4!4!4!}$, but note that $\binom{12}{4} = \frac{12!}{8!4!}$ and $\binom{8}{4} = \frac{8!}{4!4!}$, so in their multiplication the $8!$ cancels out, and we get the same number.

Comment: That's what I thought, but the solution said $\binom{12}{4,4,4}$ and didn't know what that meant. Well good to know that you can write like that :)

And thanks!

Comment: @Fourierstudent Indeed that is another way to write the same number.

Comment: Yea, I understand that now. Never seen that notation before :P

Comment: @Fourierstudent  The symbol $$\binom{n}{n_1, n_2, \ldots, n_k} = \frac{n!}{n_1!n_2! \cdots n_k!}$$ where $n = n_1 + n_2 + \cdots + n_k$ is known as a [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem).